# Names from database, in an image, doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, gd

$query = "  SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        udowers
        ";

```
    $mysqlquery = mysql_query($query);

/* IMAGE CREATION */
    $lines = mysql_num_rows($mysqlquery);
    // Create a image
        $im = imagecreate(400, 12 * $lines);

    // Set colors
        $background = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

/* END IMAGE CREATION */

    if($mysqlquery){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlquery)){
           imagestring($im, 3, 5,  $height += $lines * 12, $row['udower'], $textcolor);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        imagestring($im, 3, 5, 5, 'MySQL Error', $textcolor);
    }

    /* IMAGE CREATION */

    // Output the image
        header('Content-type: image/png');

    // Show the image
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);


    /* END IMAGE CREATION */
```

Im trying to get all the names on the column `udower` from the table `udowers`, but this doesn't work. It doesn't display anything at all. Can you guys help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line

```
$lines = count(mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlquery));
```

You are placing the pointer to the end of the results. Thus, inside your `while` loop it won't fetch any more results.

I think you are looking for the number of rows returned on that line, so you should do:

```
$lines = mysql_num_rows($mysqlquery);
```

---

Also, the line will always be the same, because you do `12 * $lines` always. You are creating a variable `$height = 12 * $lines;`, but you are not using it.

When you create that variable you should assign it to `0`, like so:

```
$height = 0;
```

Then, when you add the string to your image you should do:

```
imagestring($im, 3, 5, $height += 12, $row['udower'], $textcolor);
```

Now that you changed the height to `0`, you must adjust for the image height too:

```
$im = imagecreate(400, 12 * $lines);
```

Comment: Now it does return something but it returns `‰PNG  IHDRv¢yPLTEÿÿÿUÂÓ~IDAT(‘c``£€¶d7|“IEND®B`‚ ` and the height keeps the same although the database contains 4 rows.

Comment: Okay the height is now correct, but it created a white image now, instead of the normal image? @Shef

Comment: @Thew: A new bug was introduced on my second suggestion. I edited my answer to adjust for this. You must calculate the height when you create the image. Check the last line of code on my answer.

Comment: That still doesn't solve my problem, it still gives a blank page?

Comment: @Thew: Then you are getting any results from the DB. Try it with dummy text.

Comment: @Thew: Okay, there was still something wrong in the height calculation. I updated my answer. It should have been `$height += 12`.